# fastapi oauth2 + jwt extend exp time at every request

Tags: python, jwt, fastapi

According to the example of fastapi, we can use ouath2 and json web tokens to create login for users:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone
from typing import Annotated

from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI, HTTPException, status
from fastapi.security import OAuth2PasswordBearer, OAuth2PasswordRequestForm
from jose import JWTError, jwt
from passlib.context import CryptContext
from pydantic import BaseModel

# to get a string like this run:
# openssl rand -hex 32
SECRET_KEY = "09d25e094faa6ca2556c818166b7a9563b93f7099f6f0f4caa6cf63b88e8d3e7"
ALGORITHM = "HS256"
ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES = 30


fake_users_db = {
    "johndoe": {
        "username": "johndoe",
        "full_name": "John Doe",
        "email": "johndoe@example.com",
        "hashed_password": "$2b$12$EixZaYVK1fsbw1ZfbX3OXePaWxn96p36WQoeG6Lruj3vjPGga31lW",
        "disabled": False,
    }
}


class Token(BaseModel):
    access_token: str
    token_type: str


class TokenData(BaseModel):
    username: str | None = None


class User(BaseModel):
    username: str
    email: str | None = None
    full_name: str | None = None
    disabled: bool | None = None


class UserInDB(User):
    hashed_password: str


pwd_context = CryptContext(schemes=["bcrypt"], deprecated="auto")

oauth2_scheme = OAuth2PasswordBearer(tokenUrl="token")

app = FastAPI()


def verify_password(plain_password, hashed_password):
    return pwd_context.verify(plain_password, hashed_password)


def get_password_hash(password):
    return pwd_context.hash(password)


def get_user(db, username: str):
    if username in db:
        user_dict = db[username]
        return UserInDB(**user_dict)


def authenticate_user(fake_db, username: str, password: str):
    user = get_user(fake_db, username)
    if not user:
        return False
    if not verify_password(password, user.hashed_password):
        return False
    return user


def create_access_token(data: dict, expires_delta: timedelta | None = None):
    to_encode = data.copy()
    if expires_delta:
        expire = datetime.now(timezone.utc) + expires_delta
    else:
        expire = datetime.now(timezone.utc) + timedelta(minutes=15)
    to_encode.update({"exp": expire})
    encoded_jwt = jwt.encode(to_encode, SECRET_KEY, algorithm=ALGORITHM)
    return encoded_jwt


async def get_current_user(token: Annotated[str, Depends(oauth2_scheme)]):
    credentials_exception = HTTPException(
        status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
        detail="Could not validate credentials",
        headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
    )
    try:
        payload = jwt.decode(token, SECRET_KEY, algorithms=[ALGORITHM])
        username: str = payload.get("sub")
        if username is None:
            raise credentials_exception
        token_data = TokenData(username=username)
    except JWTError:
        raise credentials_exception
    user = get_user(fake_users_db, username=token_data.username)
    if user is None:
        raise credentials_exception
    return user


async def get_current_active_user(
    current_user: Annotated[User, Depends(get_current_user)]
):
    if current_user.disabled:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Inactive user")
    return current_user


@app.post("/token")
async def login_for_access_token(
    form_data: Annotated[OAuth2PasswordRequestForm, Depends()]
) -> Token:
    user = authenticate_user(fake_users_db, form_data.username, form_data.password)
    if not user:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail="Incorrect username or password",
            headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
        )
    access_token_expires = timedelta(minutes=ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES)
    access_token = create_access_token(
        data={"sub": user.username}, expires_delta=access_token_expires
    )
    return Token(access_token=access_token, token_type="bearer")


@app.get("/users/me/", response_model=User)
async def read_users_me(
    current_user: Annotated[User, Depends(get_current_active_user)]
):
    return current_user


@app.get("/users/me/items/")
async def read_own_items(
    current_user: Annotated[User, Depends(get_current_active_user)]
):
    return [{"item_id": "Foo", "owner": current_user.username}]
```

However we can verify that the token will expire after 30 minutes. `ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES = 30`. What I would like to have is a token that will extend its expiration time the current time + 10 minutes, everytime the user makes a request to the any endpoint in this application. As such I could keep always a period of user inactivity of which the user will not be suddenly logged out even though he is actively using the application. Is there a way to do this without ever touching on storing users on databases and only with jwts stored in the client side web browser ? What are the best practices to solve a problem like this ? update the authrization header at every
request ? set cookies ? Please advise, thanks.

EDIT: This is my attempt by using a middleware to modify the headers, but it's still not working.

```
async def get_current_user(token: Annotated[str, Depends(oauth2_scheme)]):
    credentials_exception = HTTPException(
        status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
        detail="Could not validate credentials",
        headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
    )
    try:
        payload = jwt.decode(token, SECRET_KEY, algorithms=[ALGORITHM])
        username: str = payload.get("sub")
        if username is None:
            raise credentials_exception
        token_data = TokenData(username=username)
    except JWTError:
        raise credentials_exception

    user = get_user(fake_users_db, username=token_data.username)
    if user is None:
        raise credentials_exception

    # Check if the token needs to be refreshed
    expiration_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(payload["exp"], tz=timezone.utc)
    if expiration_time - datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc) < timedelta(minutes=REFRESH_INTERVAL_MINUTES):
        # Refresh the token with a new expiration time
        access_token_expires = timedelta(minutes=ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES)
        new_access_token = create_access_token(
            data={"sub": user.username}, expires_delta=access_token_expires
        )
        return user, new_access_token

    return user , token


async def get_current_active_user(
    current_user_and_token: Annotated[User, Depends(get_current_user)]
):
    current_user,_ = current_user_and_token
    if current_user.disabled:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Inactive user")
    return current_user
```

Comment: The client can't manipulate the JWT, so you'll have to generate a new one on the server side for every response, and then hand it over to the client who uses the new JWT for any future requests. I'm not sure if a JWT is the best selection of tokens in that case (but sure, it'll work), as the main point of JWTs is separating authentication from the application itself (and using the refresh token to retrieve a new token when the old one expires). You could just use a regular, generated session id and track a server side session instead.

Comment: using the refresh token to retrieve a new token when the old one expires - I actually want to let it expire if the user is inactive, just want to keep refreshing(extending) while the user is actively making requests

Comment: You could just use a regular, generated session id and track a server side session instead. - I'm not sure I understand the idea behind this, could you please elaborate more ? thanks

Comment: The regular way of handling sessions is to generate a secure random session id, and then use that to identify which user is logged in and when they last made a request (you store this information in redis with the session id as the key - there are libraries that can do this for you). In case of using the refresh token, you'd set a limited validity for the refresh token, so if it's older than twenty minutes (10m since last request that validated), it wouldn't be valid any longer. But if you're not using any of the properties of JWTs , you could just generate a new one for every request.

Comment: I have tried to do that with a middleware but still not working as I expected, got logged out. I use the exp property of JWT

Comment: Any references to this typical way of handling with redis? If the session is is random how can we effectively find the key of the user on multiple requests? Isn't possible to handle everything only using jwts and not have to deal with redis or any other db? Say I authenticate with github. All I need to keep the data on the client side and still be able to refresh their session leveraging the exp property of jwts

Comment: You can use something like fastapi-session if you don't want to roll your own: https://jordanisaacs.github.io/fastapi-sessions/guide/getting_started/ - if you want to use JWTs, you'll have to let the original source re-sign the token to get a new expire time set, since this is usually done with the private key and that shouldn't leave the signer. You can do a something in-between; you can trust an expired JWT by storing the token and how long you want to trust it until in db/redis etc., and then keep trusting it even if it has expired.

Comment: ok, I'm thinking about not setting an expiration time on my jwt itself but then use this jwt as a key in redis with a certain TTL, whenever the user access any endpoint I extend the TTL by say 10 minutes, if the user is inactive for 10 minutes then the key will reach the TTL time and no longer in redis, thus the user is redirected to the login page. Does that sound like a good design ? thanks

Comment: Yes, that would probably work just fine. Try it out :-)